# How to add username and password at command prompt using shell script

Tags: shell

I have logged in to a host i.e `10.54.***.***` . Also I have executed a command as `bdrun sa -u root` but it asks for password to enter. How can I perform it using shell script ?

Comment: Are you going to add `bdrun sa -u root` this line in a shell script? You want that it should automatically read the password inside a shell script?

Comment: Yes..You are correct . I can add the command "bdrun sa -u root" in the script and also the password if required.

Comment: I have provided you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use redirect option to provide a password in run time in a shell script like below ( You might need to add your user account in sodo user config, check with your Unix system admin for detail ):-

```
echo "yourpassword" | sudo -S ls
```

So in your case you can use like below:-

```
echo "yourpassword" | sudo -S bdrun sa
```

Or if your password is in a file for example pass.txt

```
cat pass.txt | sudo -S bdrun sa
```

Hope this will help your. Good Luck!!